# How can I have an angular app load data in sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I'm fairly  new to angular but, i'm getting it...

Using some ui-route states, I am able to have urls (views) that progressively build with the user selected data.  Its similar to a wizard interface.  step 1 => step 2 => step 3 => final result

From start to finish there isn't much of an issue as the data is saved in a service as the user clicks along.  The problem comes when the page is refreshed or entered directly into the browser (i.e. someone sent me a link)
/step-1/step-2 should display the same data as if the user selected step 1 and then step 2

In such a case, I need to get all the user selected data up to that point. 
Get the data for step 1, when that data is loaded, get the data for step 2, then get the data for step 3, etc.  However, I only need to get the data if it has not already been retrieved.

To accomplish such an idea i need the service to return data stored in its data property or if that data is empty go get it, save it to its property and then return it.

any ideas on how to implement this?

Here is some pseudo code that illustrates what I am attempting to do in the service.  I am not certain the syntax is 100% correct but it should illustrate the point.

```
    app.factory('dataService', ['$http', '$q', '$filter', 'ngAuthSettings', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, $filter, ngAuthSettings, localStorageService) {


    var ServiceFactory = {};
    var _getData = function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        _Step1Data= localStorageService.get('Step1Data');

        if (_Step1Data) {
            $http.get('api/Step1Data').then(function (response) {
                _data = response.data.results;
                localStorageService.set('Step1Data', _Step1Data);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(_Step1Data);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    ServiceFactory.getStep1Data = _getStep1Data;
 return ServiceFactory;

}]);
```

Assuming that the process to get step 2, step 3 data is the same as step 1, the call to load the data would be as follows

```
dataService.getStep1Data ()
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.Step1Data = data;
                dataService.getStep2Data ()
                .then(function (data) {
                    vm.Step2Data = data;                    
                }, function (error) {
                    //some error stuff
                })
            }, function (error) {
                //some error stuff
            });
```

The reason for the stepped approach is that each step depends on the previous steps selected data to get the current steps data.

Comment: It looks like you have a question but you are also providing an answer already. Can you make the question more clear?
Also you are using promises (the objects with the then-method) in a bad way. See http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html for more details.

Comment: @Nils It is a question with an attempt to explain through code.  I think (from the article you provided) that I am on the right track but perhaps going the wrong direction.  How would I implement what I describe properly?

Comment: @jason you need to take use of something like this http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic

Answer (score 0):

It's the [resolve property](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) you are looking for. You can use it to resolve the step data before any step controller is instantiated. The resolved step data can then be injected in your controller.

You might combine this with your dataservice, like so:

```
step1.state({ 
  resolve: {
    step1Data: function(dataService) {
      return dataService.getStep1Data () 
    }
  }
  ....
}
```